# PrimeNg: async pipe doesn't subscribe to Observable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I've this `Observable`:

```
public adminUsers$: Observable<Array<pojo.AdministrationUser>>;
```

I'm trying to use `async` pipe in order to subscribe to it:

```
<p-table [value]="adminUsers$ | async" ...>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      ...
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      ...
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

It doesn't work.

Nevertheless, when I use `subscribe` it works fine. I mean:

```
<p-table [value]="admins">
```

and

```
this.adminUsers$
    .do(users => this.admins = users)
    .subscribe();
```

I'm not getting any log message in order to try to figure out what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
<ng-container *ngIf="adminUsers$ | async as data">
<p-table [value]="data" ...>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      ...
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      ...
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It keeps failing. Could has something to do the fact I'm create `adminUsers$` in `ngAfterViewInit`? Should I initialize this observable inside `ngOnInit` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `*ngIf="adminUsers $ | async as admins"`